# pacaur not installing latest version of package

Tags: linux, arch-linux, package-management, manjaro

Using Manjaro and trying to upgrade the `cura` package to the latest (shown as 4.8.0-1 on [AUR](https://archlinux.org/packages/community/any/cura/) at the time of writing). My installed version is 4.7.1-2, and I cannot get it to upgrade.

```
> pacaur -Q --info cura
Name            : cura
Version         : 4.7.1-2

> pacaur -Sy cura 
:: Synchronizing package databases...
 core is up to date
 extra is up to date
 community is up to date
 multilib is up to date
 sublime-text is up to date
warning: cura-4.7.1-2 is up to date -- reinstalling
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Packages (1) cura-4.7.1-2

Total Installed Size:  69.42 MiB
Net Upgrade Size:       0.00 MiB
...
```

As you can see, it wants to reinstall rather than update `cura`. I also did `pacaur -Syu` and everything is up to date.

Any idea why the latest version isn't installing, or what I can do to figure it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> shown as 4.8.0-1 on [AUR](https://archlinux.org/packages/community/any/cura/) at the time of writing

That's not AUR. "Community" is a standard pacman repository containing binary packages, and is not managed through pacaur.

Although AUR is shared between both Arch and Manjaro, the binary package repositories *are not*. Manjaro has its own pacman repositories which import Arch packages according to separate schedules for "stable" and "testing".

Using the [branch compare](https://manjaro.org/branch-compare/) tool, Manjaro repositories have `cura 4.7.2-1` in the "stable" branch, and `4.8.0-1` only in the "testing" & "unstable" branches. If you want the latest version, see Manjaro's [Switching Branches](https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php/Switching_Branches) documentation.

Comment: Wow, thank you for the info and link, that's really helpful. I was completely oblivious to that and I've been using Manjaro for years, every day, as my primary. Sheesh!